# Jolt transformation from String to Double with formatting

Tags: json, type-conversion, double, transform, jolt

Is there a way to format the Jolt transformation from string with "=toDouble" to have always one decimal?

I am trying to transform the following

Input:

```
{
  "myValue": "1"    
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "myValue": 1.0    
}
```

with transformation

```
{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
    "myValue": "=toDouble"
  }
}
```

but actual output is

```
{
  "myValue": 1
}
```

I tried using the normal **`"=toDouble"`** transformation but it does not add the missing decimal I need

Comment: Hi Emilia, welcome to SO. I reproduced after square-bracketed your current transformation( eg. `[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "myValue": "=toDouble"
    }
  }
]
` ), then got the result exactly as you expected on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

Comment: Yes, it works as expected I was wondering how I can format the transformation to double to return 3.0 when given the string "3" (when currently it returns 3)

Comment: In which platform are you trying it? It already returns `3.0` unquoted and along with a single zero as decimal part.